# How can I remove any word except specific word using pattern

Tags: android

How can I remove any word except `congratulation and .` using pattern

```
String text = "Amazement and congratulation seemed more in order than reflection.";

text = text.replaceAll("[^congratulation & .]", "");
```

Output should be:

```
congratulation.
```

Thanks advance.

Comment: Why you just don't check for "congratulation" & "." and if the string matches you just save it in a new string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this good enough?

```java
String text = "Amazement and congratulation seemed more in order than reflection.";
        boolean b = text.contains("congratulation") && text.contains(".");
        System.out.println(b);
        text = b ? "congratulation." : "Amazement and congratulation seemed more in order than reflection.";
        System.out.println(text);
```